# JSON conversion issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, coldfusion

I am trying (in Javascript an Coldfusion) to convert:

```
{"val1":"member","val2":"book","val3":"journal","val4":"new_member","val5":"cds"},
```

Into this:

```
{ member,book,journal,new_member,cds}
```

Notice that I am trying to eliminate quotes.

Is it possible to achieve this? How can I do it?

Comment: `member`, `book`, etc must be strings unless you plan on declaring variables with those names.

Comment: looks like the input is a json, but what is your expected output? CF Array? or JS Array?

Comment: What exactly is `{member,book,journal,new_member,cds}`? An object? A string?

Comment: totally confusing question.. and user do not have time to reply.

Comment: @Pritesh Patel, Be more polite! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so this:
{"val1":"member","val2":"book","val3":"journal","val4":"new_member","val5":"cds"}
is JSON.

To convert to a CF struct, you'd go like this:

```
myStruct = deserializeJSON('{"val1":"member","val2":"book","val3":"journal","val4":"new_member","val5":"cds"}');
```

(Note my examples assume we're operating within a `<CFSCRIPT>` block.)
Now you've got a simple struct with key/value pairs.  But you want a list of the values.  So let's make an empty string, then append all the struct values to it:

```
myList = "";
for (k IN myStruct) {
  myList = listAppend(myList,myStruct[k]);
}
```

Boom.  myList should now be "member,book,journal,new_member,cds"
Wrap it in curly braces if you really want to.

```
myList = "{"&myList&"}";
```

Comment: One thing to bear in mind here is that, when you loop through the keys in a struct that there is no guarantee of the order of the keys. So if the order of the items in the list is important then you will need to do this slightly differently.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I have to thank you for your replies. But some of you have to be more polite with newbies.

```
var tata = {"val1":"member","val2":"book","val3":"journal","val4":"new_member","val5":"cds"}
var arr=[]

for (var i in tata) {
    arr.push(tata[i])
}; 
console.log(arr);


wrd = new Array(arr)
var joinwrd = wrd.join(",");
console.log('{' + joinwrd + '}');
```